# Error on json.dump(dict, f) - TypeError(repr(o) + " is not json serializable")

Tags: python, json, windows, macos, serializable

I am reading a pandas dataframe and trying to write it to a file with json.dump.
This throws an error - 
TypeError(repr(o) + " is not json serializable"
TypeError: 5 is not JSON serializable

(link to error screenshot  http://postimg.org/image/lyr539w5p/

The code block at which the error occurs is shown below. Line 3 in this block raises the error

```
def write_df_to_json_file(user_array, output_filename):
try:
    fh = open(output_filename, "w")
    json.dump(user_array, fh)
except IOError:
    util.logit(3, "Error: can\'t find file or read data")
else:
    util.logit(2, str(output_filename) + " file written successful.")
    fh.close()
```

taking an output of "user_array" I get the below data.

```
user_array = {'344': {'216': 4, '215': 3, '213': 4, '297': 4, '684': 4}, '346': {'216': 3, '215': 3, '213': 3, '669': 1, '211': 4, '218': 3, '219': 2, '133': 5, '132': 4, '496': 5, '693': 4, '210': 4, '22': 5, '29': 4, '161': 3, '358': 4}, '347': {'216': 3, '378': 5, '417': 5, '435': 4}}
```

The code ran fine on OS-X with Anaconda. But on Windows, it throws the error. Three other team members in my team have tried this code on their Windows PC and they all got the same error. They also have Anaconda with Python 2.7 (same as me).

In order to do some troubleshooting on a windows pc, we copied the data (user_array) to a new file (hard coded it in the main file rather than read from the source file), and tried a json.dump. the code runs without any error!. The file was successfully created with the json dump.

I have searched online (in stackoverflow as well as other sites) and though people have faced this error, they normally have a dictionary object that couldn't be json dumped. In my case, even if this is a dictionary object, it runs on OS-X. so I assume that there is no problem with the object as such on OS-X.

Is there a particular difference between OS-X and Windows that causes this error? How do I fix this on Windows? Since, my team cannot help with the development if they cannot run the code on Windows.

--------------- Additional info ------------

Adding the blocks that end up calling this function block. 
read_csv_to_json is the first function that is called. and that in turns calls the remaining (in order shown) ending with the write_df_to_json where i get the error.
There was one point, early in the phase, where we were doing a simple json.dump on the input file after reading from csv and it ran fine on both mac and windows.  after a week, when we had all these parsing functions, this error showed up. Not sure if that's helpful info though

Read csv file

```
def read_csv_to_json(filename, separator, colnames):
  df_ratings = read_csv(filename, separator, colnames)

  holdout_split(df_ratings)


def read_csv(filename, separator, colnames):
  # read the full u data set containing 100000 ratings by 943 users on 1682 items
  data_ratings = pd.read_csv(filename, sep =separator, header = None, names = colnames)
  return data_ratings

def holdout_split(df_ratings):
  train, test = train_test_split(df_ratings, test_size = 0.2)

  parse_df_to_usercf_json(train, file_holdout_utrain)
  parse_df_to_usercf_json(test, file_holdout_utest)

  parse_df_to_itemcf_json(train, file_holdout_itrain)
  parse_df_to_itemcf_json(test, file_holdout_itest)

def parse_df_to_usercf_json(data_ratings, output_filename):
  data_ratings_sorted = data_ratings.sort_values(user_sort_colname)   # sort the data_ratings using the sort_colname
  # get distinct_userId sorted by User_id
  distinct_userId = sorted(pd.unique(data_ratings_sorted.user_id.ravel()))
  # Setting up counters to slice the dataframe for subgroups based on same userid
  user_marker = 0
  rowCounter = 0;
  rowcount = len(data_ratings_sorted.index)
  user_array = {}
  # Slicing the dataframe based on rows with the same userid and storing as dict objects
  for user in distinct_userId:  # for each distinct user
    movie_details = {}  
    for index_j, row_j in data_ratings_sorted[user_marker: rowcount].iterrows():  
                # dataframe is sliced using a user_marker that is set to beginning of the current distinct user
        rowCounter += 1  #  point rowcounter to next row
        if user == row_j['user_id']:  # till the userj in current row matches the current distinct user in the top loop
            movie_details[str(row_j['movie_id'])]=(row_j['rating'])  # create a key value pair {movie id : rating}
        else:  # if userid in current row doesnt match the distinct user in the top loop
            rowCounter = rowCounter - 1  # retreat the rowcounter one step back
            user_marker = rowCounter  # set user_marker to the next distinct user id
            user_array[str(user)] = movie_details  # store the userid and movie details as {user_id1: {movie_id,movie_rating}}
            break;  # skip to next distinct user (back to top loop)
# write the final dictionary object/array to json file
write_df_to_json_file(user_array, output_filename)
```

Comment: What are the line endings in the file? Try opening the input file as 'wb' as the line endings on osx are '\n' while windows is '\r\n' and when opening a file as 'w' python will try to read files in with the native line endings.

Comment: I opened the source file on a windows pc. it has only LF as the end characters. As you suggested, I modified the code to open input file as 'wb' just in case, but it still produces the error.

the input file is from this website - u.data in the zip file
http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/100k/
it is a csv that the program reads into a pandas dataframe. after some processing, the program tries to save it as son (using json.dump).

Comment: Jase, after replying to you, I went back and checked the older versions to see what all changed from the earlier code.

the error is in **parse_df_to_usercf_json()** (approx line 16 in the block)
            `movie_details[str(row_j['movie_id'])]=(row_j['rating'])`


Wrapping the `row_j['rating']` with int (to get `int(row_j['rating'])`), fixes the error. I still don't understand what is causing the error on windows vs Mac. the input file is in tab separated csv, so i am guessing that's somehow causes the error

please help if you can.

Comment: My guess would be that `(row_j['rating'])` is a tuple. removing the brackets or converting to int, would prevent it being a tuple. There could be subtle difference between the tuple conversion for windows vs os-x or how pandas interprets it for either OS.

Comment: Thanks Jase. I appreciate the suggestion. and in some ways, answering your initial question triggered led me to comparing the old codes, and fixing this error.

Comment: Thanks Jase. I appreciate the suggestion. the value for `row_j['rating']` is an integer between 1 and 5 in a tab separated file. so I am not sure if the tuple cause would fit into this case.

in some ways, answering your initial question led me to (luckily) resolve the error. so a big thanks for that.

what are the rules on stackoverflow for a situation like this. the initial error got fixed (mostly by luck) but root cause is still unsolved. Though I would like to know what caused it, not sure if i will.

should i close this question?? or wait for some days??